# How to destructure/move out of Drop implementing type?

Tags: rust, move-semantics

I have a managed pointer type `Uniq`, implementing `Drop`, that has a method that is supposed to consume it without running `drop` and return a `Box` of its allocation.

```rust
struct Uniq<T> { data: ManuallyDropped<Box<T>>, metadata: Metadata }

impl Uniq<T> {
   fn into_parts(/* mut */ self) -> (Box<T>, Metadata) {
     (ManuallyDrop::into_inner(self.data), self.metadata) // doesn't work

     // let Self { data, metadata } = self; // doesn't work either
   }
}

impl<T> Drop for Uniq<T> {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    // fancy_management_ledgerwork(self.metadata)
  }
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Metadata(usize);
```

How do I accomplish this kind of "destructuring move" for my type which implements `Drop`?

Note: Literally every search engine result is about people not understanding move semantics. I *do* understand move semantics and I am trying to exploit them to ensure memory safety and I cannot figure out how. I'd rather not convert the `ManuallyDrop<Box<T>>` to something less-safe-but-`Copy` like `NonNull<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ManuallyDrop::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html#method.take):

```rust
fn into_parts(mut self) -> (Box<T>, Metadata) {
    (unsafe { ManuallyDrop::take(&mut self.data) }, self.metadata)
}
```

**Edit:** As correctly mentioned by @FilipeRodrigues, if your `Drop` implementation tries to do cleanup you also need to prevent it from running, either by `std::mem::forget()` or by wrapping `self` in `ManuallyDrop`.

Comment: It's likely you'd also need to `mem::forget(self)`, else the drop impl would run and possibly access `self.data` and try to free it.

Answer (score -3):

This compiles:

```rust
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

struct Uniq<T> { data: ManuallyDrop<Box<T>>, metadata: Metadata }

impl<T> Uniq<T> {
   fn into_parts(/* mut */ self) -> (Box<T>, Metadata) {
     (ManuallyDrop::into_inner(self.data), self.metadata)
   }
}

// impl<T> Drop for Uniq<T> {
//   fn drop(&mut self) {
//     // fancy_management_ledgerwork(self.metadata)
//   }
// }


#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Metadata(usize);
```

Comment: Of course this compiles, but the OP explicitly asks about where the type implements `Drop`. Probably need to do some cleanup and the `fancy_management_ledgerwork()` was commented out only temporarily.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The OP seemed convinced that the error was in `(ManuallyDrop::into_inner(self.data), self.metadata)`, but I show here that that is not the case.

Comment: This _is_ the case. `Drop` should be there, that's the OP's requirement - it even appears in the title. Now, with `Drop` as a fact, the error is in `ManuallyDrop::into_inner()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've edited the question to also have this requirement explicitly in the body. I still think it is useful to contrast the cases with and without drop and explain why they need to be handled differently. Perhaps you could expand your answer to include such an explanation?

Comment: I disagree. The OP explicitly asks about the `Drop` case, and states they know why it is forbidden ("I _do_ understand move semantics"). Trying to explain that could be a matter for another question.